# Read a file and get specific contents in an array

Tags: c#

I'm very new to C# and I need your help.
I have a file named myData.txt with the following data in it.

```
Johnson    85  83  77  91 100  
Aniston    80  90  95  93  48   
Chen       78  81  11  90  73  
Gupta      92  83  30  69  87  
Blair      23  45  96  38  59  
Lamah     100 100 100 100 100
```

The first three scores are 'Assignments' and the last two scores are 'Exams'.
All the names should go into a 1-dimensional array 
Assignments into a 2-dim array
also Exams into a 2-dim array

My ultimate aim is to find out the average of assignments & exams for each student.

Comment: Is this a homework/assignment question?

Comment: That looks like a homework assignment.

Comment: Are you trying to do your homework? Show's the code you've got so far and we can help with your code if you have questions about it.

Comment: This question can be found in [Introduction to C++ Programming](http://books.google.nl/books?id=4Fn_P7tdOZgC&pg=PA334&lpg=PA334&dq=Johnson+85+83+77+91+100+Aniston+80+90+95+93+48&source=bl&ots=gSzR4KgypP&sig=vLCzEju9HxpJ7cqyJlGsJWm3zTw&hl=en&ei=tdp7TcrFFYjpOcfHsOsG&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Johnson%2085%2083%2077%2091%20100%20Aniston%2080%2090%2095%2093%2048&f=false) and some other books (just google the first two lines Johnson and Aniston)

Comment: Homework or not - we don't know in what format the data is being held so can't parse it.

Comment: {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name with extension:");  
            string filename = Console.ReadLine();
            string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:/Users/chaitu/Desktop/" + filename);
            Console.WriteLine("\n Text Details in the file: \n \n"+s);
            Console.ReadKey();

        }

Comment: You can start with `File.ReadAllLines` and `String.Split()` or it's `RegEx` equivalent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a homework assignment, so I'll just give you hints:

1. You can use StreamReader to open the file: [StreamReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.aspx)
2. Looks like each line ends with a new line.  You can loop through the file and read each line via 
   StreamReader's ReadLine method: [ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx)
3. It looks like each line is delimited by tab.  You can split the string returned by ReadLine on tab by using String's split method: [Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx).  The char code for tab is '\t'.  Splitting the string will put it into an array.
4. Convert the scores to a number, add, and then divide at the end to get the mean.

Comment: thank u Galbo for the writeup. I will try it and post here if I bump into any road blocks