# C# - Stream Reader or whats the best way to do it?

Tags: c#

I have a text file with something like this in it.

Tom 1 2
Jerry 3 4

using C#, I have populate this into two arrays

1st array = {Tom,Jerry} - 1 dim array
2nd array ={(1,2),(3,4)} - 2 dim array

Please help me with this. Any help would be appreciated.

```
Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name with extension:");   
string filename = Console.ReadLine();   
string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:/Desktop/" + filename);  
Console.WriteLine("\n Text Details in the file: \n \n"+s);
```

Comment: Unless you're using an old version of .NET, you should probably stick to generic `List<string>` type instead of Array types.

Comment: By the way, can you please post any code you've written so far? This looks like a homework question.

Comment: it sounds like you already solved the problem. do you have a question?

Comment: You should make a list of classes.

Comment: I'd think data structure you need is  `Dictionary<string,List<int>>` its a dictionary (Hashtable) that maps from a string to a list of integers.

Comment: I'm a complete newbie & I wrote some code..I m posting it here..not sure if it does anything  Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name with extension:");
            string filename = Console.ReadLine();
            string s = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:/Desktop/" + filename);
            Console.WriteLine("\n Text Details in the file: \n \n"+s);

Comment: Use `File.ReadAllLines` instead, it returns an array containing all lines in the file - then you need to split the individual columns

Comment: @user489512, why don't you update your question with your code sample with proper formatting, just so it's easier to read. you can use the "edit" link under your question.

Comment: May I suggest formatting your text file to make pulling out data easier.  Perhaps XML?

Comment: @all. I updated my current code ..although its not much..@kon - i dont really know using xml :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is a follow up to the [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285337/c-read-a-file-and-get-specific-contents-in-an-array) :)

More hw hints:

As I said in my last answer, splitting on tab (assuming each item is delimited by tab, which looks to be the case) will give you a 1D array of every item in a line (if you use ReadLine).

Item 1 in the ReadLine() array will be the name.  Put that into your 1D names array.
Items 2 to N of ReadLine() array will be the test scores.  Put that into your 2D scores array.

The first dimension of the scores array will be the student index.  The second dimension will be the score array.

That may sound confusing, but if you think about it, a 2D array is an array of arrays.

So even though your data file doesn't show the student index, it's implied:

```
0 Joe 100 80 77
1 Bob 65 93 100
```

Names array will look like:

```
[0] Joe
[1] Bob
```

and scores array will look like:

```
[0][0] 100
[0][1] 80
[0][2] 77
[1][0] 65
[1][1] 93
[1][2] 100
```

Notice that the index (first dimension) in the scores array coincide with the index of the names array.

Comment: thanks again galbo..have been reading a lot on what u suggested and finally tried something while googling it for my Homework(actually this is my personal work..)..its paying off..learning some basics in C#..

Answer (score 1):

There are few ways, it depends how "elegant" you want to be, and / or whether Tom, Jerry is always going to be one word.

- Parse every line with String methods
- Parse every line with RegEx
- Use [Linq to Text](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericwhite/archive/2006/08/31/734383.aspx)

Simplest way would be something like this (quick and dirty, very fragile solution):

```
var path = "fileName.txt";

var names = new List<string>();
var values = new List<KeyValuePair<int, int>>();

using (var reader = File.OpenText(path))
{
        string s = "";
        while ((s = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] arr = s.Split(' ');
            names.Add(arr[0]);
            values.Add(new KeyValuePair<int, int>(int.Parse(arr[1]), int.Parse(arr[2])));
        }
}
```

If you need you can convert lists to array

Answer (score 0):

A more complete version ;)

```
        string filename = "";
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the file name with extension:");
            filename = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEDRIVE") + Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("HOMEPATH") + "\\Desktop\\" + Console.ReadLine();
            if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filename))
                Console.WriteLine("File doesn't exist!");
            else
                break;
        } while (true);
        System.IO.StreamReader readfile = new System.IO.StreamReader(filename);

        List<string> Names = new List<string>();
        List<int[]> Numbers = new List<int[]>();
        string val = "";
        while ((val = readfile.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            if (val == string.Empty)
                continue;
            List<string> parts = val.Split(' ').ToList<string>();
            Names.Add(parts[0]);
            parts.RemoveAt(0);
            Numbers.Add(parts.ConvertAll<int>(delegate(string i) { return int.Parse(i); }).ToArray());
        }
        readfile.Close();

        //Print out info
        foreach (string name in Names)
        {
            Console.Write(name + ", ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
        foreach (int[] Numberset in Numbers)
        {
            Console.Write("{");
            foreach (int number in Numberset)
                Console.Write(number + ", ");
            Console.Write("} ");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: Thank you very much mazz.. I will let you know if you bump into any  roadblocks..this was a generic Q..my work is much more complex than this..but this is definitely a good start.I appreciate it.

Comment: this code is *way* too complicated to do something so simple. why are you assuming the file location? you should use `Using` statements for your StreamReader's so you make sure they close properly.

Answer (score 0):

I like a functional approach.

```
// var fileContent = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("somefilethathasthestuff");
var fileContent = @"Tom 1 2
Jerry 3 4";
var readData = fileContent.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
   .Aggregate(new { names = new List<string>(), data = new List<int[]>() },
       (result, line) => {
           var fields = line.Split(new []{' '}, 2);
           result.names.Add(fields[0]);
           result.data.Add(fields[1].Split(new[] { ' ' }).Select(n => int.Parse(n)).ToArray());
           return result;
        }
   );
string[] firstarray = readData.names.ToArray();
int[][] secondarray = readData.data.ToArray();
```

This uses a jagged array for the numbers, but you can copy it to a 2d if that is what you really need. Better yet, don't copy to arrays at all. Use List < string> for names and List < int[] >  for the numbers.